# Given the number of balls in urns. Find the probability of getting the desired color of balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

Question :

In one of the two urns there are $3$ white and $2$ black balls, and in the other - $2$ white and $3$ black. $3$ balls are taken out of the first urn and those of them that are of the predominant color are transferred to the second urn.

a) Find the probability that they are white.

b) If it is known that $2$ white balls were taken out of the second ballot box after the transfer, determine the probability that $2$ black balls were transferred to it.

---

My attempt  for part A:
I think  the word “predominant" in this context means which appears **more frequent/common**.

suppose - First urn has $3$ white balls and $2$ black balls

Total balls = $5$

Predominant = So, out of $3$ balls taken out atleast $2 $ should be white .

$P (\,W =3)  = \frac{3}{5} \cdot \frac{2}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3}  = \frac{1}{10}$

$P (\,W =2) = 3 \left( \frac{2}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \right) = \frac{3}{5}$

$P(W) = \frac{7}{10}$

Suppose First urn has $2$ white balls and $3$ black balls

$P(W=2) = 3 \left(\frac{2}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{4}\right) = \frac{3}{10}$

Overall probability becomes

$ P(W) = \frac{21}{100}$

---

I didn’t understand part b, can you guys please give hint for part b and verify if my solution to Part a is correct or not.

Comment: The probability for the second case is $\frac3{10}$.  There are $3$ ways to choose the balck ball to go with the two white ones, and $10$ ways to choose $3$ balls.  Alternatively, by symmetry with the first case, the probability that the majority of the balls chosen are black is $\frac7{10}$, so the complementary probability is $\frac3{10}$.

Comment: The second part isn't very clear.  I guess they mean that after the transfer, two balls are chosen uniformly at random from the second urn, and they are both white, and you are to find the conditional probability that exactly (or at least?) two black balls were transferred to it.

Comment: @saulspatz thanks for the response. yes you are right. 3 ways of getting 2 white and 1 black in second case. Btw the overall $P(W) = \frac{21}{100}$ because both cases are independent right?

Comment: @saulspatz Guess is reasonable. yes it seems a case of a conditional probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question, we could be transferring either $3$ White balls, $2$ White balls or $2$ Black balls from urn $1$ to urn $2$. $(a)$ asks the probability that the balls being transferred are white. So you should calculate $\small P(3W) + P(2W)$ or you could simply find $ \small P(2B)$ and subtract from $1$.

Now given we need to solve $(b)$, we would need all of these probabilities.

$\small \left 
\{\begin{array} 
{1} P(3W) = \dfrac{1}{10}\\
P(2W) = \dfrac{3}{5}\\
P(2B) = \dfrac{3}{10}
\end{array} 
\right.$

Answer for $(a)$ is $\small \dfrac{7}{10}$ as you can see.

For $(b)$, the question is not very clear but similar to the comments, I think it means we choose two balls from urn two and both are white.

If $B$ is the event of taking out two white balls from urn $2$ and $A$ is the event of two blacks balls transferred to it from urn $1$,

$ \displaystyle \small P(B) = P(3W) \cdot {5 \choose 2} / {8 \choose 2} + P(2W) \cdot {4 \choose 2} / {7 \choose 2} + \underbrace{P(2B) / {7 \choose 2}}$

What you see in underbrace is $ \small P(A \cap B)$ and the desired probability is $ \small \dfrac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I was going through the answer for part A. Query : wouldn’t you consider Suppose First urn has $2$ white balls and $3$ black balls scenario, because getting 2 white would mean it’s predominant . I am going through part B and will revert back .

Comment: @Gaurang in a few places, the question is not clearly written but what I think they mean is that the first urn is $3$ white and $2$ black, the second urn is $2$ white and $3$ black balls.

Comment: @Gaurang do you have any further questions /feedback on this?

Comment: sorry for delayed response, I have gone through your working and it makes sense. And I agree it should have meant urn 1 and "second ballot box" as urn 2. My understanding now : $ P(A|B) = \frac{P(2B) \cdot {7 \choose 2}}{P(3W) \cdot {5 \choose 2} / {8 \choose 2} + P(2W) \cdot {4 \choose 2} / {7 \choose 2}+ P(2B) \cdot {7 \choose 2}} $ which gives final answer as $\frac{2}{31}$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Gaurang yes, $\dfrac{2}{31}$ is correct for (b).

Comment: Thanks for your time and response @Math Lover